# InDesign: How to restore group element to master?

Tags: adobe-indesign, master-page

In Adobe InDesign, is there a way to restore an group element that's been overridden from a master to its original master state? I found this answer for restoring position to an overridden element:

> Select the offending text frame, and open the palette options in the Pages palette. Choose <kbd>Master Pages</kbd>→<kbd>Remove Selected Local Overrides</kbd>.

Unfortunately, it seems only to work for single elements, not groups. If you select an overridden group, the <kbd>Remove Selected Local Overrides</kbd> menu item will change to <kbd>Remove All Local Overrides</kbd>.

Is there some way to restore master status for a group, or is this feature simply missing from InDesign?

Answer (score 1):

If your elements are grouped in the Master Pages, you can apply 'Remove Selected Local Overrides' to the whole group.

If the dropdown menu allows only 'Remove All Local Overrides', it means that you grouped the elements outside the Master page.

All you have to do is to ungroup them before removing the overrides.

Comment: What if they were grouped in master, but then I ungrouped them for editing and re-grouped them when I finished? Am I sunk?

Comment: This sounds like a trouble-making workflow... Why do you want to overrides edited elements? All made editions will be lost then... I suggest you illustrate your question with screenshots, so we could advice on how to work with Masters. Anyway, I suggest you don't group elements in Master. I don't see any good reason to do so.

Comment: I often group items on a master page-things like all elements of a header will be grouped, and often saved as a group in my CC library for use in another document. HOWEVER, I don't ever group something that is likely to be overridden for exactly the reason that you have encountered. It may be that you have too many elements in your master pages. If you are overriding a particular element on the majority of your pages than it may not belong on a master page at all. Investigate snippets or CC libraries instead (hold Alt while placing a library item to place it in its original position).